# Azure cache worker role dies (times out) after several minutes

Tags: caching, azure

I am using Azure cache worker role and after upgrading to windows 8 and visual studio 2012, when I run the application after 1 to 10 minutes the cache object times out, I tried to create a small project and test the scenario, it happens in that application too.
when it dies, I have to restart the application or refresh the web page several times until the cache comes alive. 
Could anyone please help me out?
Thanks,
Aran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things you could try

1) Make sure you've enabled diagnostics for cache server and your cache client. Follow the link in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914135.aspx

2) I'm assuming the issue occurs only in the devfabric deployment. You can check the cache role logs in devfabric console to ascertain any issues that are getting reported. Event logs in Windows Azure channel or Application Server channel will also be of help.

3) You can deploy your test project in cloud and see if the issue is getting reproduced there.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the things that I have done so far and haven't had a lock are as following: #1- I tried both enabling and disabling the diagnostics #2- The issue occurs only on devfabric yes but moving the cache to the cloud brings latency into the development and is not achievable #3- Increased the role size #4- increased the instances #4- disabled and enabled the local cache #5- uninstalled the office as suggested in another topic #6- re installed the SDK(1.8) and non of my effort helped me out. Spec:windows 8,VS2012,Azure (1.8),it is developed in MVC and HTML5 (web Apis)